# Shorten the post title url of my grid - archive - page

Tags: wordpress, grid, title, archive, strlen

As the title says I need to shorten the post title of my grid - archive - page.
For example, my page title is "*20 ways to clean your car. Best hints and tricks 2018.*"
But on the archive page I just want to show "*20 ways to clean your car.*"

I found some code to stop after a certain amount of letters, but I would like to stop if a certain word appears. "*Best*" for example. Maybe someone can help me.

This is the code i tried so far.

```
function custom_trim_my_title( $title ) {
if ( strlen( $title ) >= 50 && ! is_singular() ) {
    $title = substr( $title, 0, 50 ) . '...';
    return $title;
}
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_trim_my_title' );
```

So hopefully someone is able to help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function custom_trim_my_title( $title ) {
    if ( !is_singular() ) {
        //if you pass $title as "this is a stop", it will return "this is a"
        $new_title = strstr($title, 'stop', true);
        if($new_title) {
            return $new_title;
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_trim_my_title' );
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your help unfortunately this is not working for me. I changed "grid" to "post" but now it doesnt even stop after the amount of letters if i use 10 for example.  The stop word is also not working.

Comment: Good Morning, thanks again. This is almost working for me. With your setting to 5 letters it did not show all of my navigationmenu. I set it to 50 and it is working. Is there a possibility to not use the amount of letters at all ? I appreciate your help.

Comment: I set to 5 just for an example. You can set to 5 or 50 or any number of letters that depends on you how you want to handle the code logic and yes you can remove that condition where you are checking for number of letters. its really depend on the app requirement or how you want to handle the code logic.

Comment: It would be very nice if you could change the function to just react to the keyword and leave the amount of letters out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was away a few days and just able to test your function. Again Thank you very much for your excellent help.

Comment: After taking a look this morning I saw, that all titles without the stop words do not show at all.

Comment: Ah! we needed to change the variable where we were getting the part of the string. check again.

Comment: Yes, great! Thank you again. It is working now. Gonna post the next problem today.